I'm trying to visualize the learning process of my deep learning model and it throws the error : No dashboards are active for the current data set
I'm trying to visualize the model training logs using TensorBoard but it is throwing the above error. Also, the logs folder in my Drive is not storing any logs of when the code is being run.
This is the code where I create the logs:
import datetime  
def create_tensorboard_callback():  
    logdir = os.path.join("drive\MyDrive\Dog Vision\logs",datetime.datetime.now().strftime(" %Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
    return tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)

After training my model on the training set, I tried to run this code:
%tensorboard --logdir /content/drive/MyDrive/Dog\ Vision/logs

but it's throwing the error as mentioned in the title of the question. Also, I'm running this on Google Colab using GPU runtime.
I'm using TensorFlow version : TF version: 2.15.0

For colab (and other linux-based os), you need to use frontslash / for paths: os.path.join("drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision/logs", ...). Otherwise, its one long foldername with backslashs.

@mhenning Yes thankyou, I changed that later on. The problem I was encountering was because I had made a log 'file' and not a 'folder' to save records, hence it was not able to save files within it.
